# Lateral Flatten Snowflake from a Variant table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, flatten, snowflake-schema, lateral

I have a variant table called `raw_json`, that houses multiple json files, which are unique to the ID but contain similar data points within each json. They live within the jsontext column. Here is a SS for context. I am trying to flatten each row of the `raw_json` table into a normal table view. The two arrays indexes need to align to assign the right values.

[image: table name is raw_json]

Here are two rows from the `raw_json` table and how the json is structured.

```
{
 "ID": "PO-103",
 "content": {
   "EEList": [
     {
       "EEListID": "PO-103-1",
       "EEProductID": "XXX1976",

     },
     {
       "EEListID": "PO-103-2",
       "EEProductID": "XXX1977",
     },
     {
       "EEListID": "PO-103-3",
       "EEProductID": "XXX1978",
     }
   ],
   "EENotesList": [
     {
       "FirstName": "John",
       "LastName": "Smith",
       "pxObjClass": "XX-XXSales-Work-XX"
     },
     {
       "FirstName": "Bob",
       "LastName": "Joe",
       "pxObjClass": "XX-XXSales-Work-XX"
     },
     {
       "FirstName": "Mike",
       "LastName": "Smith",
       "pxObjClass": "XX-XXSales-Work-XX"
     }
   ],
 }
}
```

```
{
  "ID": "PO-104",
  "content": {
    "EEList": [
      {
        "EEListID": "PO-104-1",
        "EEProductID": "XXX1979",

      },
      {
        "EEListID": "PO-104-2",
        "EEProductID": "XXX1980",
      },
      {
        "EEListID": "PO-104-3",
        "EEProductID": "XXX1981",
      }
    ],
    "EENotesList": [
      {
        "FirstName": "Sarah",
        "LastName": "Butler",
        "pxObjClass": "XX-XXSales-Work-XX"
      },
      {
        "FirstName": "Jessica",
        "LastName": "Adams",
        "pxObjClass": "XX-XXSales-Work-XX"
      }
    ],
  }
}
```

into a table like this **(I need this)**

```
+--------+----------+-------------+-----------+----------+-------------------+
|   ID   | EEListID | EEProductID | FirstName | LastName |    pxObjClass     |
+--------+----------+-------------+-----------+----------+-------------------+
| PO-103 | PO-103-1 | XXX1976     | John      | Smith    | X-XXSales-Work-XX |
| PO-103 | PO-103-2 | XXX1977     | Bob       | Joe      | X-XXSales-Work-XX |
| PO-103 | PO-103-3 | XXX1978     | Mike      | Smith    | X-XXSales-Work-XX |
| PO-104 | PO-104-1 | XXX1979     | Sarah     | Butler   | X-XXSales-Work-XX |
| PO-104 | PO-104-2 | XXX1980     | Jessica   | Adams    | X-XXSales-Work-XX |
+--------+----------+-------------+-----------+----------+-------------------+
```

I have been able to flatten the EENoteList array into a table and assign the right ID to that table. Here is my code so far: Adding in EEList values without fanning out the table is where I go wrong.

```
select
    jsontext:ID::varchar as ID,
    en.value:FirstName::varchar as FirstName,
    en.value:LastName::varchar as LastName,
    en.value:pxObjClass::varchar as pxObjClass
   -- concat(ID, EEProductID, FirstName, LastName)

    from raw_json,
    lateral flatten (input => jsontext:content:EENotesList, outer => false) en;
```

which produces this table **(I have this)**

```
+--------+-----------+----------+-------------------+
|   ID   | FirstName | LastName |    pxObjClass     |
+--------+-----------+----------+-------------------+
| PO-103 | John      | Smith    | X-XXSales-Work-XX |
| PO-103 | Bob       | Joe      | X-XXSales-Work-XX |
| PO-103 | Mike      | Smith    | X-XXSales-Work-XX |
| PO-104 | Sarah     | Butler   | X-XXSales-Work-XX |
| PO-104 | Jessica   | Adams    | X-XXSales-Work-XX |
| PO-104 | Terrence  | Williams | X-XXSales-Work-XX |
+--------+-----------+----------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so mostly this answer is the preamble to get the data into a CTE, but "iff" the order of the two arrays are in lockstep, you can just use the index of the flatten to access the raw array of the other type:

```
WITH raw_json AS (
select PARSE_json(column1) AS jsontext FROM VALUES 
 ('{
 "ID": "PO-103",
 "content": {
   "EEList": [
     {
       "EEListID": "PO-103-1",
       "EEProductID": "XXX1976",

     },
     {
       "EEListID": "PO-103-2",
       "EEProductID": "XXX1977",
     },
     {
       "EEListID": "PO-103-3",
       "EEProductID": "XXX1978",
     }
   ],
   "EENotesList": [
     {
       "FirstName": "John",
       "LastName": "Smith",
       "pxObjClass": "XX-XXSales-Work-XX"
     },
     {
       "FirstName": "Bob",
       "LastName": "Joe",
       "pxObjClass": "XX-XXSales-Work-XX"
     },
     {
       "FirstName": "Mike",
       "LastName": "Smith",
       "pxObjClass": "XX-XXSales-Work-XX"
     }
   ],
 }
}'), ('{
  "ID": "PO-104",
  "content": {
    "EEList": [
      {
        "EEListID": "PO-104-1",
        "EEProductID": "XXX1979",

      },
      {
        "EEListID": "PO-104-2",
        "EEProductID": "XXX1980",
      },
      {
        "EEListID": "PO-104-3",
        "EEProductID": "XXX1981",
      }
    ],
    "EENotesList": [
      {
        "FirstName": "Sarah",
        "LastName": "Butler",
        "pxObjClass": "XX-XXSales-Work-XX"
      },
      {
        "FirstName": "Jessica",
        "LastName": "Adams",
        "pxObjClass": "XX-XXSales-Work-XX"
      }
    ],
  }
}') 
)
select
    jsontext:ID::varchar as ID,
    en.value:FirstName::varchar as FirstName,
    en.value:LastName::varchar as LastName,
    en.value:pxObjClass::varchar as pxObjClass,
    jsontext:content.EEList[en.index].EEListID::text as EEListID,
    jsontext:content.EEList[en.index].EEProductID::text as EEProductID
    from raw_json,
    lateral flatten (input => jsontext:content:EENotesList, outer => false) en;
```

this results in:

```
ID  FIRSTNAME   LASTNAME    PXOBJCLASS  EELISTID    EEPRODUCTID
PO-103  John    Smith   XX-XXSales-Work-XX  PO-103-1    XXX1976
PO-103  Bob     Joe     XX-XXSales-Work-XX  PO-103-2    XXX1977
PO-103  Mike    Smith   XX-XXSales-Work-XX  PO-103-3    XXX1978
PO-104  Sarah   Butler  XX-XXSales-Work-XX  PO-104-1    XXX1979
PO-104  Jessica Adams   XX-XXSales-Work-XX  PO-104-2    XXX1980
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! Where did you find how to use EEList[en.index]? Could not find any indexing within the Snowflake documentation..

Comment: could you expand off the first part of your answer? I have never used a CTE and am lacking the context.

Comment: just assumed it would work a while back, given it's a Javascript access style on a JSON object.. Am quite sure there is a get_member like accessor also. I just use `.` or `:` to access the sub elements.

Comment: A CTE (common table expression) https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/queries-cte.html is a expression that makes named table like thing you can access elsewhere, so much like a sub-select with an alias, but if you join to that sub expression many times, it does not need to be defined multiple-times.. I often use then you logically separate steps of processing, because the optimizer can and does mash it all up as if it's sub-select...